# Can we use the "predict" function for a gee model?

Tags: r, prediction, generalized-estimating-equations

Can we use the "predict" function for a gee model? I know from the gee model we can use "fitted.values" to get the predicted values for the data used to build the model. However, I want to use the gee regression results to generate predicted values for a test data.

```
data(warpbreaks)

smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(warpbreaks))
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(warpbreaks)), size = smp_size)
train <- warpbreaks[train_ind, ]
test <- warpbreaks[-train_ind, ]

gee_model = gee(breaks ~ tension, id=wool, data=train, 
corstr="exchangeable")

predict(gee_model, train)
predict(gee_model, test)
```

The last two lines result in the following error.

```
"Error in seq_len(p) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer"
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why is this question closed?

Comment: You can predict manually by using the coefficient predicted by the GEE model. You can also use `geepack` library which does work with the "predict" function (though still does the same).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use the predict function for a gee model in R. However, as suggested previously ([How can I estimate model predicted means (a.k.a. marginal means, lsmeans, or EM means) from a GEE model fitted in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109369/how-can-i-estimate-model-predicted-means-a-k-a-marginal-means-lsmeans-or-em)), you can use the LSmeans function in the [doBy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doBy/index.html) package to get predictions for new data. Please note that this creates predicted population means, for better predictions for individuals it may be better to use a random effects model.

```
library(gee)
library(doBy)

data(warpbreaks)
smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(warpbreaks))
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(warpbreaks)), size = smp_size)
train <- warpbreaks[train_ind, ]
test <- warpbreaks[-train_ind, ]

gee_model = gee(breaks ~ tension, id=wool, data=train, 
corstr="exchangeable")

pop.mean <- LSmeans(gee_model,effect="tension")

predictions.test <- ifelse(test$tension=="L", pop.mean[[1]][1],
                  ifelse(test$tension=="M", pop.mean[[1]][2],
                         ifelse(test$tension=="H", pop.mean[[1]][3],NA))
                  )
```